# Facebook app login using PHP SDK not working: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I recently stumbled upon problem when trying to login via facebook app login. First of all, I've already read every possible thread about problems with fb login, followed every possible tutorial but with no effect.  Everything worked perfect when it was first done but I've just found out it's not working. I get this:

[image]

I get the message - domain is not included in the app domain field. But in fact it is as you can see below:

[image]

Help me Stack Overflow, you are my only hope.

Comment: Double check that you have the latest Facebook SDK installed. It seems like there was an issue that they (claim to have) fixed about 1,5, months ago: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/issues/939

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply updating to 5.6.2 solves the problem.

Comment: Not saying that updating the SDK isn't the solution, but how do you know that the OP isn't already running that version and that the issue is something else?